# In Spring Boot 2.1.3 not able to exclude Couchbase Auto Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, couchbase

I have a java project configured with gradle 5 with spring boot 2.1.3. I am trying to create a simple rest application to use Mongo-db repository and JPA with MySQL with a simple service.

I am **not** intended to use couch-base.  although Couch base/reactive Auto configuration is loading and creating an issue, I am not able exclude Couch auto configuration and getting below exception -

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/couchbase/config/AbstractReactiveCouchbaseDataConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist.
```

I tried to exclude all Couchbase Autoconfiguration without any success

```
"@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { 
       SpringBootCouchbaseConfigurer.class, 
       CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, 
       CouchbaseDataProperties.class, 
       CouchbaseReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, 
       CouchbaseReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class, 
       CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration.class,
       CouchbaseAutoConfiguration.class,
       CouchbaseConfiguration.class
})"
```

If I could add spring-data-couchbase dependency it works. but I don't want to include Couch-base unnecessarily with application.

I am looking for a help/workaround to exclude the Couch-base auto configuration.

Comment: Can you share your pom?

Comment: I am using gradle .5.2.1. unfortunately, I can add only 15 words in comment section at max! and not sure how to attach file here.

Comment: It's interesting that couchbase is loaded if it's not within the `pom.xml`. Is it your IDE's classpath setting that's bugging out? And if you want to exclude all Couchbase classes there should be a class that has `@componentScan` that you can use to exclude everything Couchbase related.

Comment: I upgraded to spering boot 2.1.4 but now I started getting error
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration$WebFluxConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/reactive/config/DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I am not using any webflux library neither I have any related code.
looking for somoene's help to resolve this issue

Comment: @Ravendra please include your gradle build file in the question segment with code formatting or an image. To get the dependency tree. Use command "gradle dependencies". Provide the output in your question segment and not as a comment to convey the issue.